# Javascript check if character is a vowel

Tags: javascript, character

I've looked at plenty of questions related to mine here but they're all using different methods to the method I have to use. I'm aware it's a very long winded way to find out when there are simpler ways but I'm just following instructions.

Why doesn't the below code work? The function checks if it's vowel.
Then the input is checked to see if it's length is 1. If it's 1, call the function. If it's greater than 1, ask for another input until the length is 1.

I see now that boolean doesn't exist in JS. I guess this question is invalid now!

```
function isVowel(x){

    boolean result;

        if(x == "A" || x == "E" || x == "I" || x == "O" || x == "U" ) {
            result = true;
        }
        else{
            result = false;
        }
    return result;
    }

    var input;


    input = prompt("Enter a character ");
    input = input.toUpperCase();
    if(input.length == 1){
        isVowel(input);
        }
    }
    else{
        while(input.length != 1){
            prompt("Enter a character ");
            if(input.length == 1){
                isVowel(input);
            }
        }
    }

    alert(isVowel(input));
```

Comment: `boolean` does not exist in javascript, use `var` instead

Comment: Oh. At least I found that out early in my learning.

Comment: You're free to use any code formatting and indentation you want in your own code, but when asking for help, please take the time to format the code in some reasonable, consistent manner, perhaps using a service likt http://jsbeautifier.org/.

Comment: `function is_vowel(str)
{
 return str.match('a|e|i|o|u/i') ? true : false;
}` is a better way to write that function - this would be case insensitive incase that matters

Comment: @Novocaine: Good point, well made!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `isVowel` in three places, and just throwing away the return value in the first two. If you want to see the return value in the first two places, show it (via `alert` as in  your last example, or any of several other ways).

There are other issues as well:

- As [devqon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926994/javascript-check-if-character-is-a-vowel/26927041#comment42400118_26926994), you've used `boolean` rather than `var`, so the code won't parse
- Any time you find yourself writing:

  ```
  var result;
  if (condition) {
      result = true;
  } else {
      result = false;
  }
  return result;
  ```

  ...stop and make it:

  ```
  var result = condition;
  return result;
  ```

  So for `isVowel`:

  ```
  function isVowel(x) {

      var result;

      result = x == "A" || x == "E" || x == "I" || x == "O" || x == "U";
      return result;
  }
  ```

  (You can, of course, make that a one-liner, but it's easier to debug this way.)
- You have an extra `}` after your `if` block (reasonable, consistent formatting would have make that obvious)
- Your `while` loop will never end, because you never update `input` with the return value of the `prompt`
- Rather than an `if` followed by a `while`, use `do-while`

Here's an updated version with just those changes

```js
function isVowel(x) {

  var result;

  result = x == "A" || x == "E" || x == "I" || x == "O" || x == "U";
  return result;
}

var input;

do {
  input = prompt("Enter a character ");
  if (input.length == 1) {
    alert(isVowel(input));
  }
} while (input.length != 1);
```

Comment: a,e,i,o,u  - will return "false" . To FIX it Add x= x.toUpperCase();

Comment: @MPV - I don't think this was a generalized question about detecting vowels. It ws about why the OPs code didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

The answer can be one line and is short and sweet. See below.

```
    function isVowel(x) { 
        return ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(x) != -1); 
    }
```

Comment: This is real single line solutions  
`const isVowel = x=> !!x.match(/[aeiou]/i)`

Answer (score 4):

Try This function no matter what uppercase or lowercase

```js
function isVowel(x) {  return /[aeiouAEIOU]/.test(x); }

var input = '';
while (input.length != 1) {
  input = prompt("Enter a character ");
}
alert(isVowel(input));
```

Comment: *"I'm aware it's a very long winded way to find out when there are simpler ways but I'm just following instructions."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Although you have followed the original poster's instructions to the letter, your answer is nevertheless, not the best example of code that the asker could use. TangChanrith has posted an elegant and simple solution to the problem in addition to your informative answer. However, people searching for a similar solution in the future can either pick your solution which is informative to the OP but ultimately inefficient, or TangChanrith's but at least they have a choice.

Answer (score 3):

Minified arrow function version of [Tang Charinth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26927463/11107541) with breakdown of the regex and a flag tweak.

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal and its [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

- `/` regex boundary
- `[]` group bracket expression matching single chars it contains
- `aeiou` chars to test against
- `i` case insensitive flag

```js
const isVowel = char => /[aeiou]/i.test(char);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to add much on top of [Tang Charinth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26927463/11107541)

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Comment: Thank you [David Fong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/david-fong) and [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) for your feedback. I originally scanned the answers and missed [Tang's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26927463/11107541), which I like better. So I'm tweaking my suggestion and adding an explanation

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a mathematical solution, so I came up with this:

```
function isVowel(c) {
    c = c.charCodeAt(c);
    var magicNumber = 2198524575;
    c = (c > 96) ? (c-32) : c;
    if( c < 65 || c == 75 || c > 90) 
        return false;
    var div = magicNumber / c;
    var diff = div - Math.floor(div);
    if( diff == 0 )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You send it the character as a string. It will detect any of these: AEIOUaeiou

The magic number is just the ascii codes for AEIOU multiplied together.  The check c==75 is because K is the only character that also gets a perfect division, as long as we constrain the checks to the upper case letters.

Note: If you can remove `c = c.charCodeAt(c);` the code would run faster.  It's almost as fast as other methods, and its possible this code could still be improved.

Answer (score 2):

function is_vowel(char){
  let listofVowel= ['a','i','e','o','u','A','I','E','O','U'];

return listofVowel.includes(char);
}

console.log(is_vowel('a'));

Comment: I use Es6     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){
     var vowel_string = "aieouAIEOU";
     input = prompt("Enter a single character...");
     if (input.length == 1){
       if (vowel_string.contains(input)){
            alert(input + " is a vowel");
  }
 }
 else{
     alert("Enter a single character");
 }   
})();
```

Comment: *"I'm aware it's a very long winded way to find out when there are simpler ways but I'm just following instructions."*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short ES6 helper to test for a vowel

```
const isLetterAVowel = (str) => {
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(str.charAt(0).toLowerCase());
}
```

A consonant returns `false`:

```
console.log(isLetterAVowel('cat'));
```

A vowel returns `true`:

```
console.log(isLetterAVowel('emu'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**To check if the given string contains a vowel or not in a simple way**

```
var input = "kad aeiou";
function vowvelOrNot(input){
  var str = input.toLowerCase();
  if(str.length > 0){
    for(i=0; i <= str.length; i++){
      switch (str[i]){
        case 'a':
          var flag_a = true;
          break;
        case 'e':
          var flag_e = true;
          break;
        case 'i':
          var flag_i = true;
          break;
        case 'o':
          var flag_o = true;
          break;
        case 'u':
          var flag_u = true;
          break;
      }
      if(flag_a && flag_e && flag_i && flag_o && flag_u){
        return "Given string is Vowel";
      }
    }
    return "Given string is Not Vowel";
  }else{
    return "please enter the correct value";
  }
}
var res = vowvelOrNot(input);
console.log(res);
```