# Check if a word begins with a vowel?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a basic js query, let's say I have

```
document.getElementById('test').value();
```

Inside this value is the word "Idea".

How can I create a function which checks if this begins with I, or any vowel? In the simplest way possible?

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926994/javascript-check-if-character-is-a-vowel

Comment: Probably some regex test with case insensitive flag.

Comment: `value` is a property, not a method

Comment: Test "YOUR_STRING"[0] with your condition...

Answer (score 9):

You can use regular expressions `^[aieouAIEOU].*` to check if it starts with vowel.

http://jsfiddle.net/jpzwtm3f/1/

```
var testStr = 'Eagle'
var vowelRegex = '^[aieouAIEOU].*'
var matched = testStr.match(vowelRegex)
if(matched)
{
alert('matched');
}
else
{
alert('not matched');
}
```

Comment: If you want to have every vowels you can use :
var vowelRegex = '^[aieouâêîôûäëïöüàéèùœAIEOUÂÊÎÔÛÄËÏÖÜÀÉÈÙŒ].*';
(usefull for french :) )

Answer (score 3):

Referring to what [Muhammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754893/muhammad-ramzan) pointed out.

You can use a regex like so `/^[aeiou].*/i`.

- `Caret ^ = beginning of the string`
- `[aeiou] = match any character inside brackets`
- `.*      = match any amount of characters after [Greedy]`
- `i       = case-insensitive`

---

```js
function testVowels(e) {
  const regex = new RegExp('^[aeiou].*', 'i');
  let inputVal = $(e.target).val();
  let regexOutput = regex.test(inputVal);
  
  // If is true
  if(regexOutput) {
    $('#debug').text("Test: True");
  } else {
    $('#debug').text("Test: False");
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type something:<hr>
<input type="text" onkeyup="testVowels(event)" /><br>
<span id="debug"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a an array of vowels.

```
['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

To check if a array contains a certain value, use `indexOf(value) !== -1`

and to get around upper/lowercase differences, bump the char down `toLowerCase()`

so you get something like this

```
function firstIsVowel(s) {
    return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(s[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expression

```
/^[aeiou]/i

Use ^ when you want to start your checking in this example i want to start with any 
vowels

[] Inside the bracket is any character we want to match

i The i flag means we are ignoring if its uppercase or lowercase
```

Comment: Best solution 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code assuming you store the value in a variable named str. I will be storing the value `Idea` in it.

```js
let str = "Idea";

function startsWithVowel(str) {
  let fstLetter = str.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  if (fstLetter=='a' || fstLetter=='e'|| fstLetter=='i' || fstLetter=='o' || fstLetter=='u') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(startsWithVowel(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex or a simple conditional. Modified solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488028/how-do-i-check-for-vowels-in-javascript).

```
function beginsWithVowel(word) {
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(word[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}
```