# How to find if the first letter of a string is a vowel in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a project and as the title states, I am trying to find if the first letter of a string in javascript is a vowel. So far I have code that looks like this.

```
function startsWithVowel(word){
    var vowels = ("aeiouAEIOU"); 
    return word.startswith(vowels);
}
```

Comment: @AndrewL64 different language but logic is still applicable.

Comment: @A.J.Uppal I have retracted the close vote. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a word begins with a vowel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241871/check-if-a-word-begins-with-a-vowel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite close, just slice the word using `[0]` and check that way:

```js
function startsWithVowel(word){
   var vowels = ("aeiouAEIOU"); 
   return vowels.indexOf(word[0]) !== -1;
}

console.log("apple ".concat(startsWithVowel("apple") ? "starts with a vowel" : "does not start with a vowel"));
console.log("banana ".concat(startsWithVowel("banana") ? "starts with a vowel" : "does not start with a vowel"));
```

Answer (score 4):

This works if you don't care about accent marks:

```js
const is_vowel = chr => (/[aeiou]/i).test(chr);

is_vowel('e');
//=> true

is_vowel('x');
//=> false
```

But it will fail with accent marks commonly found in French for example:

```js
is_vowel('é'); //=> false
```

You can use [`String#normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to "split" a character: the base character followed by the accent mark.

```js
'é'.length;
//=> 1
'é'.normalize('NFD').length;
//=> 2
'é'.normalize('NFD').split('');
//=> ["e", "́"] (the letter e followed by an accent)
```

Now you can get rid of the accent mark:

```js
const is_vowel = chr => (/[aeiou]/i).test(chr.normalize('NFD').split('')[0]);

is_vowel('é');
//=> true
```

---

*Credit to [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/1244884) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/990904/1244884)*

Answer (score 3):

`startsWith` only accepts a single character. For this sort of functionality, use a regular expression instead. Take the first character from the word (`word[0]`), and see whether its character is included in a case-insensitive character set, `[aeiou]`:

```
function startsWithVowel(word){
    return /[aeiou]/i.test(word[0]);
}
```

```js
function startsWithVowel(word){
    return /[aeiou]/i.test(word[0]);
}

console.log(
  startsWithVowel('foo'),
  startsWithVowel('oo'),
  startsWithVowel('bar'),
  startsWithVowel('BAR'),
  startsWithVowel('AR')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 oneliner:

```
const startsWithVowel = word => /[aeiou]/i.test(word[0]);
```

Comment: Although your way to do it is pretty but if (just for a testing purpose ) provide index more then the length of string. it's says true for them. vowels.indexOf(word[0])) is perfect for this purpose.

Comment: Can you give more details about this one-liner function? In my case this is not working:`set enum(text) { let startsWithVowel = (text) => /[aeiou]/i.indexOf(text[0]); this.title = startsWithVowel ? "Créer un nouvel ${text.slice(0, -1)}"  : "Créer un nouveau ${text.slice(0, -1)}" }`